# Proxy running node-react application

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I just created a react-node-SQL app and I want it to run on Google Cloud (not firebase)

My React app runs on different port and my node app runs on different port.

I followed this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-create-react-app-work-with-a-node-backend-api-7c5c48acb1b0/) and added this line in my react-app package.json but I didn't worked out i.e `href` in button was still going to localhost:8081 but It didn't worked

I had my node running on port 8080, In `package.json` of my react app i added `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"` and in button when I did `href="/api/status"` it was going to `localhost:8081` on which the react app was running

Now, Is it possible to run both node and react under the same project? or we need to create separate project for them.

**[Update:]** I am using webpack, In my webpack config file, I added this

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/': 'http://localhost:8080'
    }
  },
```

The problem with this, that even in my react app, on Startup (running on 8081) when it opens the webpage localhost:8081/ it throws an error saying **cannot get the page**

but if I do something like this

```
  devServer: {
        proxy: {
          '/api': 'http://localhost:8080'
        }
      },
```

it opens the page homepage normally. Now my api and callback uRL after authentication aren't configured with have prefix as api.

Comment: did you add the proxy line?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty I had my node running on port 8080, In `package.json` of my react app i added `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080/"` and in button when I did `href="/api/status`" it was going to `localhost:8081` on which the react app was running

Answer (score 1):

Basically, when you do an ajax request from react app, like `axios` or `fetch` it will use the `proxy: <..>` for the backend url. But, `href` doesn't work with proxies. In that case you need to manually configure proxy using the `setupProxy.js` documented in the manual proxy page.

Check out this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6031):

> Same error here, it still routes to localhost:3000/api/auth/google, my
>   CRA version is 2.1.3 It seems http-proxy-middleware is the only
>   working way. I have to Configuring the Proxy Manually

From the [react doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually):

> If the proxy option is not flexible enough for you, you can get direct
>   access to the Express app instance and hook up your own proxy
>   middleware.
>
> You can use this feature in conjunction with the proxy property in
>   package.json, but it is recommended you consolidate all of your logic
>   into src/setupProxy.js.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Just updated the question can you go through it as well.